# How can I get the actual function name instead of 'lambda' when lambda function is used in agg() in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, aggregate

For any given dataframe with multiple columns:

let's say I have two functions defined which I will later use for `agg()`

The two functions are:

```py
def sd(col):
    return( col.std() )

iqr = lambda col: col.quantile(0.75) - col.quantile(0.25)
```

Now when I used these two functions in multiple columns of a df as:

```
my_df[ ['col_1','col_2'] ].agg( func= [sd,iqr] )
```

I get the correct result (for both funcs) with correct name for the function `sd`. However for the lambda function `iqr`, I get `<lambda>` instead of `iqr`. *Output included at the last.*

Is there a way I can get `iqr` instead of `<lambda>` (preferably) automatically, if not, through hard-code?

Also, I need to use `lambda` and not conventional `def` as I have to use compound function like this:

```
def qnt( qth ):
    func_lmd = lambda col: col.quantile( q= qth )
    return func_lmd
```

Thank you in advanced for y'all suggestions.

My output is:

```
              col1       col2
sd          9.922446    0.624355
<lambda>    16.583333   0.565000            <-- function name is lambda instead of iqr
```

Comment: Lambdas don't have names. Assigning a function to a variable doesn't change the function's name. E.g. if you do `lqr = sd`, and then do `print(lqr)` it will say that the function name is `sd`, not `lqr`.

Comment: If you want it to have a name, why don't you use `def lqr`?

Comment: is there a hard-code to get col name while using ```.agg()``` ?

Comment: Also could you suggest how would I use `def ` for this function: 


```python
def qnt( qth ):
    func_lmd = lambda col: col.quantile( q= qth )
    return func_lmd
```

Comment: You can use a nested `def`

Comment: `def qnt(qth): def fnc_lmd(col): return col.quantile( q= qth ); return fnc_lmd`

Comment: Yes.....tried and tested.... thank you so much :)